# Sorting Array: Bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public static void sortByNumber(Course[] list) {
    Course temp = new Course();

    boolean fixed = false;

    while(fixed == false) {
        fixed = true;
    for (int i = 0; i<list.length-1; i++) {

        if (list[i].getNum() > list[i+1].getNum()) {
            temp.setNum(list[i].getNum());
            temp.setDept(list[i].getDept());
            temp.setTitle(list[i].getTitle());

            list[i] = list[i+1];
            list[i+1] = temp;
            fixed = false;
        }
    }
    }}
```

This is a method for sorting courses offered by university.

For example, each course has its department (i.e. MATH), number (i.e. 263) and title (i.e. Ordinary Differential Equations for Engineers) - MATH 263 Ordinary Differential Equations for Engineers.

In my another class, I have created an object Course, which has its own accessors and mutators (i.e. getNum(), setNum(), getDept(), so on).

Given a long list of courses, I wanted to arrange them according to their course numbers, but the above method does not seem to work.

Can someone hint reason for this?

Comment: arrange as in least to most, {100,101,102...201,202,...}

Comment: Hint: Look at your setters. You are not thinking in terms of object oriented programming. What was temp before you called its setters? What is it after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `temp` variable is a reference to a `Course` object.

Actually the array `list` is an array of references to `Course` objects.

You only need to change references and not copy the object's values into `temp`. Just do `temp = list[i];` to keep a reference to the i-th element of the array.

Comment: I see that my redundancy was inefficient, but why does it produce incorrect result?

Comment: You were pointing the i-th reference to the next object (the i+1-th one, that's OK), but made that i+1-th reference always point the temp object instead of pointing to the i-th object.

Comment: You can initialize the `temp` inside your loop which will be correct but THIS will be reduntant and inefficient. Pointing your temp to i+1 is the best solution. Check out the bubble sort algorithm on RosettaCode and some other sorting alternatives to learn. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Java

Answer (score 0):

I would rather implement the  `Comparable` interface.

```
class Course implements Comparable<Course>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Course other){
        return this.getNum().compareTo(other.gerNum());
    }
}
```

And then you can use `Array.sort(Course[] list)` to sort your courses array.